# the return of main function causes an exception

Tags: c, visual-studio, winpcap

i am writing a program sending RAW Socket using winpcap, everything seems OK, the packet has been sent successfully. but when the sending behavior is over, Windows shows a dialog telling me:

```
SendRawSocketsConsole.exe has stopped working
```

and the details is:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: SendRawSocketsConsole.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f51de63
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16915
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49caf
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00055401
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2052
  Additional Information 1: e8ad
  Additional Information 2: e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863
  Additional Information 3: e8ad
  Additional Information 4: e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

i debugged the program, and found that the program stopped finally at the line():

```
if (pHead == NULL)
{
    *errno_tmp = ENOMEM;
     RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_FuncCheckSet_hook,(1));
}
```

its in `dbgheap.c`, and the value of `errno_temp` is zero, which caused the error, i dont know what condition may cause the error, i tried to build `release` instead of `debug`, but still failed, can anyone give any idea? any help appreciated. im using VS2008 and Win7 :)

Comment: Crashes like this usually indicate some kind of memory corruption somewhere in your program. Check your code for out-of-bounds accesses and other errors related to dynamic memory.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when i compiled the program using VC++6.0, no error occurred, its very strange @ComicSansMS

Comment: That is typical for this kind of error. You probably just got lucky in VC6 and it didn't touch any important data. That is what makes them so hard to debug: You can never be sure where they are hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the point is: `seudo = new unsigned char(sizeof(P_HDR) + strlen(dump));`, should be 
`seudo = new unsigned char[sizeof(P_HDR) + strlen(dump)];`

Comment: and also thank you, @ComicSansMS, it indeed a memory corruption.